# How to use a pandas dataframe field to regex-replace text in another field in Python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to find text in one field of a pandas dataframe ("text") based on another field ("words") of it.

```
#import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['I like apple pie','apple'],['Nice banana and lemon','banana|lemon']], columns=['text','words'])
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r''+df['words'].str, '*'+group(0)+'*')
df
```

I'd like to mark the found words with *.
How can I do that?

The desired output is:
**I like *apple* pie

Nice *banana* and *lemon***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the word from `words` and use backreference in the substitution to wrap it in `*`:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['I like apple pie','apple'],['Nice banana and     lemon','banana|lemon']], columns=['text','words'])

df['text'] = df['text'].replace(r'('+df['words']+')', r'*\1*', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                            text         words
0             I like *apple* pie         apple
1  Nice *banana* and     *lemon*  banana|lemon
```

Comment: That's the syntax, I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC using  `(?i)` is same as `re.I`

```
df.text.replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.words,value="*")
Out[131]: 
0        I like * pie
1    Nice * and     *
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Since you update the question

```
df.words=df.words.str.split('|')
s=df.words.apply(pd.Series).stack()
df.text.replace(dict(zip(s,'*'+s+'*')),regex=True)
Out[139]: 
0               I like *apple* pie
1    Nice *banana* and     *lemon*
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: I'd like to wrap the found words with *-s. I posted the desired result in the original question.